# Postgres - How to retrieve default value in table structure query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to retrieve some table's structures with the column default values using this query :

```
SELECT column_name, is_nullable, character_maximum_length, udt_name, default_value
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema = 'public'
AND table_name = 'USER'
ORDER BY ordinal_position
```

But I'm unable to find the correct value to select the default values. I tried "default_value" but it doesn't work...

Comment: Do you really have a table named `USER` - that is a bad idea as `user` is a keyword and the name of a built-in function as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/infoschema-columns.html) the default value is available in `column_default`

```sql
SELECT column_name, is_nullable, character_maximum_length, udt_name, column_default
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema = 'public'
AND table_name = 'USER'
ORDER BY ordinal_position
```